# Java: Continuing iteration through an arraylist only when the right menu item is selected

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, console-application

I'm trying to create a console app that iterates through an arrayList of meal ideas every time the correct menu item is selected. The problem is that I can't seem to continue the iteration every time the correct menu item is selected, it just restarts the loop.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> meals = new ArrayList<String>();
meals.add("pasta");
meals.add("potatoes");
meals.add("pork");
String select = "";    

while(!select.equals("q")){
    System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
    System.out.println("\t 1. See next suggestion.");
    System.out.println("\t 2. <Another option>");
    System.out.println("\t 3. <Another option>");
    select = in.next();

    switch(select){
        case "1":
            //Here's where the problem is:
            int nextIdea = 0;
            while(){
                System.out.println("\tToday: " + meals.get(nextIdea));
                nextIdea++;
                break;
            }
            System.in.read();
            break;
    }

}
```

After the user selects to show the daily selection, the first item in the list should be displayed then it should go back to the "What would you like to do menu" then next time the user selects option 1 in the menu it should display the next item in the menu but instead it restarts the loop. I understand it's because the counter variable ("nextIdea") is set to zero every time before the loop executes but how can I get it to remember which arrayList index number was last used and then use that next time the user selects to see the daily meal. The list should only reset to 0 once it's gone through all the items in the list.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: while() -> what is the condition in while. syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the nextIdea index out of the first loop. Then you also don't have to iterate the list when the user selects "See next suggestion." - You just display the next idea:

```
int nextIdea = 0;
while(!select.equals("q")){
    System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
    System.out.println("\t 1. See next suggestion.");
    System.out.println("\t 2. <Another option>");
    System.out.println("\t 3. <Another option>");
    select = in.next();

    switch(select){
        case "1":
            System.out.println("\tToday: " + meals.get(nextIdea));
            nextIdea++;
            System.in.read();
            break;
    }
}
```

So, basically, you don't need the inner loop to iterate over the meal ideas. You already do the iteration with the outside loop: Every time the user selects menu item #1, you show her the next idea.

You should also make sure that nextIdea is always a valid index in the array list. Something like:

```
case "1":
    if(nextIdea >= meals.size()) {
        nextIdea = 0;
    }
    System.out.println("\tToday: " + meals.get(nextIdea));
    nextIdea++;
    System.in.read();
    break;
```

Comment: Thank you!! That was such an easy fix and I never even thought about it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, instantiate nextIdea outside of the while loop like you have mentioned.

Then, includ a simple if statement which checks if the nextIdea has reached the end, like so:

```
while(true)
{
    if (nextIdea < meals.size())
    {
        System.out.println("\tToday: " + meals.get(nextIdea));
        nextIdea++;
    }

    else
    {
       nextIdea = 0;
    }

    break;
}
```

You didn't have a condition in the while loop, so I'm assuming you meant 'true' which means it'll run infinitely until broken out of.

Although, technically, the loop here isn't really doing anything as it just runs once and breaks out, so you can just get rid of it like so:

```
if (nextIdea < meals.size())
{
    System.out.println("\tToday: " + meals.get(nextIdea));
    nextIdea++;
}

else
{
   nextIdea = 0;
}
```

I think you need to think carefully about what it is you actually want to achieve and what the best way to do this is.

Feel free to ask my further questions.